# Attaching Files to QC defect by Java code from local machine

Tags: hp-quality-center

When we open a defect in QC generally we need to attach the logs of the server
i want to Make an application such that It will take files(logs from all the relevant server) and stores in our local machine and then we can rar those files and directly attach it to QC defect mentioned by person opening defect
Now my question is how can i access the defect and attach the files to that particular defect

Please give your suggestions if any

Answer (score 1):

QC has a published COM API called [Open Test Architecture](http://feelsgood11.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/how-to-use-quality-center-open-test-architecture-api/), (OTA) you can use that to load the relevant defect and attach the file to it. You can find relevant examples in QC Help for OTA.

Note that this is a COM API, if you insist using Java client to communicate with it, then you will have to use a Java to COM bridge like [JIntegra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/) (there is a free one as well, but I don't remember it's name).

But if you can write your client in VB6, C++ or .NET it will be much simpler (and cheaper) than writing it in Java.

For more Java to COM bridges, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138028/is-it-possible-to-call-a-com-api-from-java)

Comment: Hi Alex,

Thanks for replying
can you tell me how i can do this by using C++
as per your comment this would be eaiser to implement 
One more thing which i would like to ask is can you give me any other link from which i can read OTA other than Help from QC

Comment: In C++ you can use ATL templates for accessing COM objects which are exposed by OTA. Regarding online documentation for OTA, I haven't seen any, but I did not look for it to hard since I do have it in help. I guess that if you don't find it, you can try to download trial version of QC from HP and get it from there.

Comment: BTW, why C++, it will be much easier to do it in C# or VB6. If licenses for VS is the issue, then you don't have to use VS to program it, you can use SharpDevelop instead. Belive me, I had the "pleasure" of writing a COM client both in C++ and vb6 and .net, and I must say unless you enjoy pain I would go with .net or VB6.