# Why does return/redo evaluate result functions in the calling context, but block results are not evaluated?

Tags: return, rebol, tail-call-optimization, trampolines, rebol3

Last night I learned about the /redo option for when you `return` from a function.  It lets  you return *another* function, which is then invoked at the calling site and reinvokes the evaluator from the same position

```
>> foo: func [a] [(print a) (return/redo (func [b] [print b + 10]))] 

>> foo "Hello" 10
Hello
20
```

Even though `foo` is a function that only takes one argument, it now *acts like a function that took two arguments*.  Something like that would otherwise require the caller to know you were returning a function, and that caller would have to manually use the `do` evaluator on it.

Thus without `return/redo`, you'd get:

```
>> foo: func [a] [(print a) (return (func [b] [print b + 10]))] 

>> foo "Hello" 10
Hello
== 10
```

`foo` consumed its one parameter and returned a function by value (which was not invoked, thus the interpreter moved on).  Then the expression evaluated to 10.  If `return/redo` did not exist you'd have had to write:

```
>> do foo "Hello" 10
Hello
20
```

This keeps the caller from having to know (or care) if you've chosen to return a function to execute.  And is cool because you can do things like tail call optimization, or writing a wrapper for the return functionality itself.  Here's a variant of `return` that prints a message but still exits the function and provides the result:

```
>> myreturn: func [] [(print "Leaving...") (return/redo :return)]

>> foo: func [num] [myreturn num + 10]

>> foo 10
Leaving...
== 20
```

But functions aren't the only thing that have behavior in `do`.  So if this is a general pattern for *"removing the need for a DO at the callsite"*, then why doesn't this print anything?

```
>> test: func [] [return/redo [print "test"]]

>> test 
== [print "test"]
```

It just returned the block by value, like a normal return would have.  Shouldn't it have printed out "test"?  That's what `do` would...uh, do with it:

```
>> do [print "test"]
test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is because it is generally unnecessary to evaluate a block at the call point, because blocks in Rebol don't take parameters so it *mostly* doesn't matter where they are evaluated. However, that "mostly" may need some explanation...

It comes down to two interesting features of Rebol: static binding, and how `do` of a function works.

### Static Binding and Scopes

Rebol doesn't have scoped word bindings, it has static direct word bindings. Sometimes it seems like we have lexical scope, but we really fake that by updating the static bindings each time we're building a new "scoped" code block. We can also rebind words manually whenever we want.

What that means for us in this case though, is that once a block exists, its bindings and values are static - they're not affected by where the block is physically located, or where it is being evaluated.

However, and this is where it gets tricky, function contexts are weird. While the bindings of words bound to a function context are static, the *set of values* assigned to those words are *dynamically* scoped. It's a side effect of how code is evaluated in Rebol: What are language statements in other languages are functions in Rebol, so a call to `if`, for instance, actually passes a block of data to the `if` function which `if` then passes to `do`. That means that while a function is running, `do` has to look up the values of its words from the call frame of the most recent call to the function that hasn't returned yet.

This does mean that if you call a function and return a block of code with words bound to its context, evaluating that block will fail after the function returns. However, if your function calls *itself* and *that* call returns a block of code with its words bound to it, evaluating *that* block before your function returns will make it look up those words in the call frame of the *current* call of your function.

This is the same for whether you `do` or `return/redo`, and affects inner functions as well. Let me demonstrate:

Function returning code that is evaluated after the function returns, referencing a function word:

```
>> a: 10 do do has [a] [a: 20 [a]]
** Script error: a word is not bound to a context
** Where: do
** Near: do do has [a] [a: 20 [a]]
```

Same, but with `return/redo` and the code in a function:

```
>> a: 10 do has [a] [a: 20 return/redo does [a]]
** Script error: a word is not bound to a context
** Where: function!
** Near: [a: 20 return/redo does [a]]
```

Code `do` version, but inside an outer call to the same function:

```
>> do f: function [x] [a: 10 either zero? x [do f 1] [a: 20 [a]]] 0
== 10
```

Same, but with `return/redo` and the code in a function:

```
>> do f: function [x] [a: 10 either zero? x [f 1] [a: 20 return/redo does [a]]] 0
== 10
```

So in short, with blocks there is usually no advantage to doing the block elsewhere than where it is defined, and if you want to it is easier to use another call to `do` instead. Self-calling recursive functions that need to return code to be executed in outer calls of the same function are an exceedingly rare code pattern that I have never seen used in Rebol code at all.

It could be possible to change `return/redo` so it would handle blocks as well, but it probably isn't worth the increased overhead to `return/redo` to add a feature that is only useful in rare circumstances and already has a better way to `do` it.

However, that brings up an interesting point: If you don't need `return/redo` for blocks because `do` does the same job, doesn't the same apply to functions? Why do we need `return/redo` at all?

### How DO of a Function Works

Basically, we have `return/redo` because it uses exactly the same code that we use to implement `do` of a function. You might not realize it, but `do` of a function is really unusual.

In most programming languages that can call a function value, you have to pass the parameters to the function as a complete set, sort of how R3's `apply` function works. Regular Rebol function calling causes some unknown-ahead-of-time number of additional evaluations to happen for its arguments using unknown-ahead-of-time evaluation rules. The evaluator figures out these evaluation rules at runtime and just passes the results of the evaluation to the function. The function itself doesn't handle the evaluation of its parameters, or even necessarily know *how* those parameters were evaluated.

However, when you `do` a function value explicitly, that means passing the function value to a call to *another* function, a *regular* function named `do`, and then that magically causes the evaluation of additional parameters that *weren't even passed to the `do` function at all*.

Well it's not magic, it's `return/redo`. The way `do` of a function works is that it returns a reference to the function in a regular shortcut-return value, with a flag in the shortcut-return value that tells the interpreter that *called* `do` to evaluate the returned function as if it were called right there in the code. This is basically what is called a trampoline.

Here's where we get to another interesting feature of Rebol: The ability to shortcut-return values from a function is built into the evaluator, but it doesn't actually use the `return` function to do it. All of the functions you see from Rebol code are wrappers around the internal stuff, even `return` and `do`. The `return` function we call just generates one of those shortcut-return values and returns it; the evaluator does the rest.

So in this case, what really happened is that all along we had code that did what `return/redo` does internally, but Carl decided to add an option to our `return` function to set that flag, even though the internal code doesn't need `return` to do so because the internal code calls the internal function. And then he didn't tell anyone that he was making the option externally available, or why, or what it did (I guess you can't mention everything; who has the time?). I have the suspicion, based on conversations with Carl and some bugs we've been fixing, that R2 handled `do` of a function differently, in a way that would have made `return/redo` impossible.

That does mean that the handling of `return/redo` is pretty thoroughly oriented towards function evaluation, since that is its entire reason for existing at all. Adding any overhead to it would add overhead to `do` of a function, and we use that a *lot*. Probably not worth extending it to blocks, given how little we'd gain and how rarely we'd get any benefit at all.

For `return/redo` of a function though, it seems to be getting more and more useful the more we think about it. In the last *day* we've come up with all sorts of tricks that this enables. Trampolines are **useful**.

Comment: Thanks for the reverse-engineering work looking through the code to answer this.  I often answer questions here regarding open source things by saying [well, it's open source, go look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649493/).  Now that Rebol is open source, we finally can!  :-)

Answer (score 4):

While the question originally asked why `return/redo` did not evaluate blocks, there were also formulations like: "is cool because you can do things like tail call optimization", "[can write] a wrapper for the return functionality", "it seems to be getting more and more useful the more we think about it".

I do not think these are true. My first example demonstrates a case where `return/redo` *can* really be used, an example being in the "area of expertise" of `return/redo`, so to speak. It is a variadic sum function called `sumn`:

```
use [result collect process] [
    collect: func [:value [any-type!]] [
        unless value? 'value [return process result]
        append/only result :value
        return/redo :collect
    ]
    process: func [block [block!] /local result] [
        result: 0
        foreach value reduce block [result: result + value]
        result
    ]
    sumn: func [] [
        result: copy []
        return/redo :collect
    ]
]
```

This is the usage example:

```
>> sumn 1 * 2 2 * 3 4
== 12
```

Variadic functions taking "unlimited number" of arguments are not as useful in Rebol as it may look at the first sight. For example, if we wanted to use the `sumn` function in a small script, we would have to wrap it into a paren to indicate where it should stop collecting arguments:

```
result: (sumn 1 * 2 2 * 3 4)
print result
```

This is not any better than using a more standard (non-variadic) alternative called e.g. `block-sum` and taking just one argument, a block. The usage would be like

```
result: block-sum [1 * 2 2 * 3 4]
print result
```

Of course, if the function can somehow detect what is its last argument without needing enclosing paren, we really gain something. In this case we could use the `#[unset!]` value as the `sumn` stopping argument, but that does not spare typing either:

```
result: sumn 1 * 2 2 * 3 4 #[unset!]
print result
```

Seeing the example of a `return` wrapper I would say that `return/redo` is not well suited for `return` wrappers, `return` wrappers being outside of its area of expertise. To demonstrate that, here is a `return` wrapper written in Rebol 2 that actually is outside of `return/redo`'s area of expertise:

```
myreturn: func [
    {my RETURN wrapper returning the string "indefinite" instead of #[unset!]}
    ; the [throw] attribute makes this function a RETURN wrapper in R2:
    [throw]
    value [any-type!] {the value to return}
] [
    either value? 'value [return :value] [return "indefinite"]
]
```

Testing in R2:

```
>> do does [return #[unset!]]
>> do does [myreturn #[unset!]]
== "indefinite"
>> do does [return 1]
== 1
>> do does [myreturn 1]
== 1
>> do does [return 2 3]
== 2
>> do does [myreturn 2 3]
== 2
```

Also, I do not think it is true that `return/redo` helps with tail call optimizations. There are examples how tail calls can be implemented without using `return/redo` at the [www.rebol.org](http://www.rebol.org) site. As said, `return/redo` was tailor-made to support implementation of variadic functions and it is not flexible enough for other purposes as far as argument passing is concerned.

Comment: Combining `sumn` with R3's `#` shorthand syntax for `none` could at least save some typing: `sumn 10 20 30 #`.

Comment: The "expression barrier" notion of ` \ ` as literal unset is even nicer I think.  `x: sumn 10 20 30 \ print x`...and it provides a good tool for helping authors show the boundary even when a function is non-variadic (should they feel it's illustrative to do so).  # does not work well for this, IMO.