# Rebol Quickstart

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2, red

I've been meaning to try out rebol (or red). I think it might be the perfect fit for my next project.
I've downloaded and tested out red 0.5.4, and REBOL/View 2.7(http://www.rebol.com/download-view.html)

However, there are a couple of roadblocks for a complete beginner to rebol:

1. Red seems to be still in alpha so it is out of the question
2. There seems to be 3+(?) branches: [REBOL3 - what is the difference between the different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510930/rebol3-what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-branches/31517518?s=1|0.1923#31517518) I'm not sure what to start on
3. Most of the documentation on the internet is for rebol 2 and documentation explaining the differences between rebol 2 and 3 is.. non existent? (case in point: parse is different)

So, my question is, if I were to develop a (Windows) gui application with http access (including http authentication) where should I start?

Should I use rebol 2, rebol 3(ren c), or red?

p.s. first question ever!

Comment: p.s. is it just me, or does stackoverflow switch between http and https?

Comment: Welcome, and StackOverflow is a good resource...but this question is a better fit for a [forum (?) or similar](http://rebolforum.com).  See ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)--and notice specifically *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*  If you collect just a few points with `actual [code questions (or answers)]`, you can join the chat here. :-)

Comment: [I've posted an answer on that Rebol Forum](http://rebolforum.com/index.cgi?f=printtopic&topicnumber=47), which is more liberal about allowing conversation and opinions... there will likely be some feedback there.  Red also has a Google Group and an IM.

Comment: @Brett has compiled a collection of [differences between Rebol 2 and Rebol 3](http://www.codeconscious.com/rebol/r2-to-r3.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red is in alpha so you've already excluded it. Rebol 3 with view is not supported by anyone as far as I know. So this leaves you with Rebol 2. I think you can still purchase a license for the SDK. And there are many people who can answer support questions.

Comment: After reading the forums and websites. This is the way I've decided to move forward. Use rebol2/view and port to red or rebol 3 in future if needed. I'm not sure about the differences between SDK and VIEW. Or if I would need it

Comment: Sorry, can't upvote your answer yet

Comment: View is free to use. If you want to distribute a binary with hidden sources, or need built in db connections, you'll need the SDK.

Comment: got it for you geeky