# Programmatically editing macros in excel

Tags: java, vba, excel

We have a large number of excel files. I want to modify the macros in each of the file. The change is same across all file. A specific use case would be to change initialization of string from `ABC` to `abc`.

Is there a programmatic way to access and edit a particular function. Java would be preferable but other language would be okay.

Comment: Any COM "aware" language can modify an Excel file with the COM interface. Although there are [several tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138028/is-it-possible-to-call-a-com-api-from-java) to achieve that, Java may not be the best suited language. You can however do it with C#, C++, VB.net, even PowerShell

Comment: You can do this even with VBA http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in VBA by programming the VBE (VB editor).  This references 'Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3.' which presumably you could do in Java too.  Have a look at this guide: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: The file is password protected. Will this work in that case too?