# Windows firewall on/off using JAVA

Tags: java, windows-firewall

Is there any way to **on/off windows firewall** using **Java**? I search on google and stack-overflow, i don't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

There is a COM interface that allows the firewall state to be controlled.  Here's an example from [MSDN in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726(v=VS.85).aspx).

Note that your Java program needs elevated permissions to change the setting.

For tips on using COM from Java, see

[Is it possible to call a COM API from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138028/is-it-possible-to-call-a-com-api-from-java)