# Getting GUI tree of Windows OS using Java

Tags: java, windows, accessibility

Hi I'm currently working on making a utility software on Windows OS(mainly Windows 8.1).

I would like to get GUI tree with Microsoft Active Accessibility API from Java.
Is it possible? Although I googled this issue, I couldn't find the best way to do this.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft Active Accessibility API is a COM interface you should be able to do what you want with any of the options from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138028/is-it-possible-to-call-a-com-api-from-java) question.