# Use JNA to CreateObject of a COM object I have no .class for

Tags: java, com, jna

I have seen examples like this

```
MsWordApp comObj = this.factory.createObject(MsWordApp.class);
```

in other questions here [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138028/is-it-possible-to-call-a-com-api-from-java).

My problem is that I need to create an object like it is done in a vbscript example:

```
Set tdc = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
```

In this Scenario the createObject would need to process a String, not a class. How can I translate this vbscript to Java / JNA ?

Comment: Java can't create an object it doesn't know, so if you don't have .class, then you can not create the object

Comment: You could perhaps generate some Java class source codes and compile on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript's `CreateObject` is essentially `CLSIDFromProgID` followed by `CoCreateInstance`, with error handling.

VBScript always uses late binding, so you're interested in `IDispatch` support.

It seems JNA provides this through `COMBindingBaseObject`:

```
new COMBindingBaseObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection", false)
```

Then, use the provided `IDispatch` to invoke methods and get or set properties.

[Reference](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/PlatformLibrary.md#com-support).